# Where does a theme hook come from?

Tags: theming, 8

I know I could use something like hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter() to add a suggestion, which would allow me to get a template rendered, but I wish someone would explain where the original ones come from in the first place.

For example, in the Twig debugging html, I'm seeing this:

```
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'page' -->
```

...but I don't know where that 'page' hook came from.  I can't exactly grep for 'page' in core.  Could anyone give me an explanation the order in which these things happen, and how they're connected:

- Something creates a list of possible templates to use (How?)
- Drupal grabs/renders the files specified from this list, from the theme or parent theme
- Something adds new suggestions to existing template names, allowing for specificity
- You can add your own template names to elements, which causes it to look for those files

Even a good direction to look in core would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hook `page` comes from a hook_theme implementation in `system.module`:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function system_theme() {
  return array_merge(drupal_common_theme(), [
    ...
```

which calls the function `drupal_common_theme()` in `theme.inc`:

```
function drupal_common_theme() {
  return [
    // From theme.inc.
    'html' => [
      'render element' => 'html',
    ],
    'page' => [
      'render element' => 'page',
    ],
    ...
```

The hook name is the top key of the array in hook_theme. See the documentation in [D8 Theme API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme/8.3.x). The theme suggestions are built in core the same way as in custom code.

Comment: Thank you so much for that, it feels relieving to know where things come from.